# mongoose updateOne not loading

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need help: I have created this schema in mongoose:

```
 const ordineSchema= mongoose.Schema({
cliente: {
    type:String,
required: true,
unique: true},
costo: Number,
piatti:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Piatto'
}],
transazione:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Transazione'
    },
stato: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
enum:{
    values:['in attesa', 'in lavorazione', 'completo'],
    message: '{VALUE} is not supported'
}
  }
  })
```

and i have created theese 2 methods: addOrdine and updateStatoOrdine

```
addOrdine: (req, res, next)=>{
    cliente=req.body.cliente;
    costo=req.body.costo;
    stato=req.body.stato;
    Ordine.create({"costo":costo, "cliente":cliente, "stato":stato}, (error, savedDocument)=>{
        if(error){console.log(error)
        res.end('ERROR');};
        res.send('Ordine inserito');
    })
   },

updateStatoOrdine: (req, res, next) =>{
     Ordine.updateOne({cliente: req.body.cliente},{$set: {stato: req.body.stato}}),
    (error)=>{
        if(error){console.log(error)
        res.end('ERROR')}else{res.send('Ordine aggiornato')}
    }
},
```

the first method works flawlessly, the second one instead indefinitely loads and does nothing. This is what looks like in insomnia when I try it [pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frAZ8.png)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I used `async/await`:

```
updateStatoOrdine: async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const update = await Ordine.updateOne({
      cliente: req.body.cliente
    },{
      $set: {
        stato: req.body.stato
      }
    });
    res.send( update)}
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.end('ERROR')}
  }
}
```